# ERROR: rm: cannot remove 'kernel.img': No such file or directory

Tags: makefile

I've been trying to get my Raspberry Pi 4 OS (not Linux or anything, I'm making an OS from scratch) to work.

The Makefile has this error when I use the command "make":

```
rm -rf objects
rm -rf SuperPiOS.elf
rm SuperPiOS.img
rm: cannot remove 'SuperPiOS.img': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:110: clean] Error 1
```

I can't figure out why it wouldn't work though.

Here's the Makefile:

```makefile
CFLAGS= -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -mcpu=cortex-a72+nosimd
CXXFLAGS= -ggdb3 -O0 -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -mcpu=cortex-a72+nosimd
CSRCFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS= -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib
IMG_PATH= ../
CFILES= $(wildcard *.c)
OFILES= $(CFILES:.c=.o)
GCCFLAGS= -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles
GCCPATH= gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf
GCCPATHAARCH= $(GCCPATH)/aarch64-none-elf/bin
GCCPATHBIN= $(GCCPATH)/bin
ASMCFLAGS= -f elf32 -F dwarf -g -w+all
ASM= -s

# Location of the files
KER_SRC = ../src/kernel
KER_MENU_SRC = ../src/kernel/menu
KER_HEAD = ../include
COMMON_SRC = ../src/common
UI_IMAGES = ../images/ui
SPE_GAMES = ../spe_games
DINOBYTE = $(SPE_GAMES)/dinobyte
OBJ_DIR = objects
ASMSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.s)
KERSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.c)
#KERSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.c)
COMMONSOURCES = $(wildcard $(COMMON_SRC)/*.c)
KERSOURCESCPP = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.cpp)
DINOBYTESOURCES = $(wildcard $(DINOBYTE)/src/*.cpp)
#KERSOURCESCPP = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.cpp)
#KERMENUSOURCESC = $(wildcard $(KER_MENU_SRC)/*.c)
#KERMENUSOURCESCPP = $(wildcard $(KER_MENU_SRC)/*.cpp)
UISOURCES = $(wildcard $(UI_IMAGES)/*.png)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.s, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(ASMSOURCES))
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.s, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(ASMSOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERSOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERSOURCESCPP))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(COMMON_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(COMMONSOURCES))
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_MENU_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERMENUSOURCESC))
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_MENU_SRC)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERMENUSOURCESCPP))
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(UI_IMAGES)/%.png, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(UISOURCES))

#Dinobyte objects [include Dinobyte headers here] (do later)
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(DINOBYTESOURCES)/src/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(DINOBYTESOURCES))

#Headers
HEADERS = $(wildcard $(KER_HEAD)/*.h)


IMG_NAME=SuperPiOS

#build: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
#$(CC) -T linker.ld -o $(IMG_NAME).elf $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) #needs indent
#$(OBJCOPY) $(IMG_NAME).elf -O binary $(IMG_NAME).img #needs indent

#$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.s
#mkdir -p $(@D) #needs indent
#$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -c $< -o $@ #needs indent

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.s
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $(KER_SRC) -o $(OBJ_DIR)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.c
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/%.c
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.cpp
    $(GCCPATHBIN) arm-none-eabi-cpp $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/%.cpp
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(COMMON_SRC)/%.c
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_MENU_SRC)/%.c
#   mkdir -p $(@D)
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -I$(KER_HEAD) -c $< -o $@ $(CSRCFLAGS)

#$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_MENU_SRC)/%.cpp
#   mkdir -p $(@D)
#   $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -I$(KER_HEAD) -c $< -o $@ $(CSRCFLAGS)
$(IMG_NAME)%.img: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles $(OBJECTS) -T linker.ld -o $(IMG_NAME).elf
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-objcopy -O binary $(IMG_NAME).elf  $(IMG_NAME).img

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    rm -rf $(IMG_NAME).elf
    rm $(IMG_NAME).img

run: build
    qemu-system-arm -m 128 -no-reboot -M raspi4 -serial stdio -kernel kernel.elf

dbg:
    $(GDB) kernel.elf
dbgrun: build gdbinit
    qemu-system-arm -m 128 -no-reboot -M raspi4 -serial stdio -kernel kernel.elf -S -s

.PHONY: gdbinit
gdbinit:
    echo "target remote localhost:1234" > .gdbinit
    echo "break kernel_main" >> .gdbinit
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  The most obvious one is that this command:

```
rm SuperPiOS.img
```

is failing because that's how the `rm` program is defined: if the file you ask it to delete doesn't exist then `rm` will fail.  If you don't want that to happen, add the `-f` option:

```
rm -f SuperPiOS.img
```

Now if the file doesn't exist, `rm` will silently succeed.  You can examine the man pages for the `rm` program.

However, the higher level question you are probably asking is, why when I run `make` is it running the `clean` rule?

That's because make, if you don't specify what to build on the command line, always builds the *first* explicit target.  In this makefile the first explicit target you defined is `clean`, so that's what's built.  This is almost certainly not what you want.  You should figure out what target you want to build when you run `make` with no arguments and put the rule for that target as the first explicit target in your makefile.

Other than this rule it normally doesn't matter much what order rules come in (if you have multiple pattern rules that could all build the same target, for example multiple pattern rules to build `%.o`, then order can matter there).

Comment: So how would I do that? Because I'm a little bit confused

Comment: ??? Move the `clean` rule to the bottom of the makefile, or at least somewhere so it's not the first explicit rule in the makefile.  I don't know how to say it more clearly than that.